# Как можно вывести только те данные, которые актуальны сейчас?

Tags: python, json, api, requests, datetime

Простите за глупый вопрос.
Как можно сделать, чтобы при выводе данных я получал только данные, которые были бы актуальны на данный момент, т.е. отправление и пребывание поездов за этот день, но время которых уже прошло мне не нужно. Нужны только данные актуальные, с этой таблицы https://voronezhvokzal.ru/raspisanie-poezdov/

код:

```
current_date = date.today()

link = f"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5&station=s2014001&transport_types=train,suburban&direction=departure&date={current_date}"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = json.loads(r.text)
for train in trains["schedule"]:
    print(f"Станция: {trains['station']['title']}")
    print(f"Отправка в {train['departure']}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")



link = f"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5&station=s2014001&transport_types=train,suburban&event=arrival&date={current_date}"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = json.loads(r.text)
for train in trains["schedule"]:
    print(f"Станция: {trains['station']['title']}")
    print(f"Прибытие в: {train['arrival']}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")
```

Я так понимаю, что нужно использовать Модуль Datetime. Я читал документацию, но не понял как мне это сделать. Часовой пояс в Json **2021-01-19T19:20:00+03:00**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Значения в `train['departure']` и `train['arrival']` являются строками и их можно привести к типу `datetime`.

После, значения можно сравнить с текущим временем и не показывать те, что наступили раньше.

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT
import requests


current_date = DT.date.today()

link = f"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5&station=s2014001&transport_types=train,suburban&direction=departure&date={current_date}"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = r.json()
for train in trains["schedule"]:
    departure = train['departure']
    departure = DT.datetime.fromisoformat(departure)
    if departure < DT.datetime.now(departure.tzinfo):
        continue

    print(f"Станция: {trains['station']['title']}")
    print(f"Отправка в {departure}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")

print('\n' + '-' * 100 + '\n')

link = f"https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=f3a6c277-5bcc-48d9-95ed-6373ba1b6fa5&station=s2014001&transport_types=train,suburban&event=arrival&date={current_date}"
r = requests.get(link)
trains = r.json()
for train in trains["schedule"]:
    arrival = train['arrival']
    arrival = DT.datetime.fromisoformat(arrival)
    if arrival < DT.datetime.now(arrival.tzinfo):
        continue

    print(f"Станция: {trains['station']['title']}")
    print(f"Прибытие в: {arrival}")
    print(f"Номер поезда: {train['thread']['number']}")
    print(f"Направление: {train['thread']['title']}\n")
```